# jQuery: Accordian Toggle - Close Div When Sibling Is Open

Tags: jquery, toggle

I've got an accoridan toggle that currently works fine, except I want it so only one item is expanded at a time. When you open one item and go to open another I'd like the original one to close.

Any idea on what I should add to my code to get this to work?

Here's the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.internal').hide();

$('.slider').click(function() {

    $(this).next('.internal').slideToggle();
}).toggle(function() {
    $(this).children("span").html("minus sign");
}, function() {
    $(this).children("span").html("plus sign");
});

});
```

I set up a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Lg9Mn/17/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.internal').hide();

    $('.slider').click(function() {
        $('.internal').not($(this).next('.internal')).hide();
        $('.slider').not($(this)).children("span").html("plus sign");

        if( $(this).next('.internal').is(':visible')){
            $(this).children("span").html("plus sign");
        }
        else{
            $(this).children("span").html("minus sign");
        }
        $(this).next('.internal').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Need to add this to your click event

```
$('.internal').not($(this).next('.internal')).hide();
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/Lg9Mn/32/)**

Comment: Thanks for the ultra quick response! One problem here (similar to the other answer) is that when you click a new item the original item still has a minus sign next to it after it closes. Is there any way to change this back to the plus sign when the div closes?

Comment: @Jake ..Added that change .. Check the Updated post

Comment: Apologies, I didn't notice the update! This seems to work, but only for a couple of clicks. You can see if you click slide 1, then slide 2, then slide 1 again, slide 1 will have a plus sign beside it even though it's open.

Comment: @jake.. You don't need the toggle Event in the first place ... Check the Updated Code in the Post

Comment: Ah I gotcha now... This works perfectly! I added return false; to the end so that when you click the link it doesn't jump your browser to the top of the page.  Thanks a million!

Answer (score 1):

Simply hide all the elements with class `internal` (using `slideUp`) before you show the correct one:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.internal').hide();

    $('.slider').click(function() {
        $('.internal').slideUp();
        $('.slider').not($(this)).children("span").html("plus sign");
        if($(this).next('.internal').css("display") == "none"){
            $(this).next('.internal').slideDown();
            $(this).children("span").html("minus sign");
        }else{
            $(this).next('.internal').slideUp();
            $(this).children("span").html("plus sign");
        }
    })
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lg9Mn/30/

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! The only issue here is that once you click a new item the original item still has a minus sign next to it after it closes. Is there any way to change this back to the plus sign when the div closes?

Comment: Thanks for the fix! This does seem to work better, but it's not quite perfect :)  You can see if you click slide 1, then slide 2, then slide 1 again, slide 1 will have a plus sign beside it even though it's open.

Comment: Hmmm everything looks great now except for one new issue... When I click an item my browser jumps to the top of the page.  hehe, sorry to be so difficult :) I do really appreciate your help though!